# SQL group by month in Laravel selectRaw

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to group data by various formats such as hour, day, month and year based on a `created_at` column in my database, I always need to return a valid date and am having trouble with that part.

The following gives me a valid date on `date`:

```php
User::selectRaw('DATE(created_at) as date, COUNT(*) as total')->groupBy('date')->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeeks(4))->whereNull('email_verified_at')->get();
```

But if I want to group by month, `date` simply becomes `10`, how can I change this?

```php
User::selectRaw('MONTH(created_at) as date, COUNT(*) as total')->groupBy('date')->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeeks(4))->whereNull('email_verified_at')->get();
```

Comment: Which database is this sat on top of? Each DBMS has different syntax for dates. (MYSQL8, MYSQL5.X, Oracle, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc)

Answer (score 0):

well you have selected the month , why would you expect to receive the full date ?

also when you group by month , it means across all years , days ... so it doesn't make sense to have a full date anyway (i did see your condition but even that can include 2 different years )

but you can have something like this which will give you the date of first found row

```
User::selectRaw('MONTH(created_at) as month, DATE(created_at) as date,  COUNT(*) as total')
->groupBy('month')
->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeeks(4))
->whereNull('email_verified_at')->get();
```